# How to embed unembedded fonts in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, ghostscript, postscript

I am currently working on a project where I need to embed fonts into an existing PDF file that has some fonts that are not embedded. My primary goal is to ensure that all fonts used in the PDF are embedded, even if I have to use substitute fonts. I initially attempted to achieve this using PDFlib in Node.js, but I encountered an issue where the embedded fonts had different names, such as "Arial-7572" instead of "Arial."

Here's the code snippet I used with PDFlib:

```
const firstPage = await pdfDoc.getPages()[0];
pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
const Arial = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fs.readFileSync('Arial.ttf', null));
firstPage.setFont(Arial);
```

I'm open to solving this problem with PDFlib, I'm also interested in alternative approaches using other libraries or tools like Ghostscript. My main objective is to have all fonts in the PDF file embedded, even if I need to substitute fonts. For instance, instead of embedding "Arial," I might embed a similar font like "Arimo." However, when inspecting the PDF properties, all fonts should be listed as embedded.

Can anyone provide guidance or a solution to achieve this font embedding goal in Node.js or through other libraries/tools?

Please don't suggest any website that can solve this issue.

Comment: If you supply a font with the correct name to Ghostscript, then the PDF interpreter will find that font when you process the input PDF file. If you then use the pdfwrite device to output a new PDF file, then by default that file will have the fonts embedded in it (NOTE you will have to define an empty NeverEmbed array to get the base 14 fonts embedded) You can define substitute fonts in the Ghostscript fontmap.GS or cidfmap files (cidfmap is for CIDFonts, fontmap.GS is for regular fonts). The syntax for defining fonts is documented in the files as comments. I can't help you with node.js though

Comment: @KenS can you please give me the gs for this?

Comment: @KenS I tried to do the following command in Ghostscript `gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dCompressFonts=true input.pdf` but there is font called as AlbanyWTJ which is already embedded and it is showing an error: CIDset in subset font is incomplete (font contains glyphs that are not listed. How can I embed this font once again correctly?

Comment: Ah well that's a different problem. Basically you probably can't because there's a chance the subset CIDFont uses a custom CMap, so removing it and rerunning with a substitute may well not work. On the other hand you probably don't need to worry. The CIDSet is pretty much irrelevant and widely ignored, it is also optional. You could just wipe it out entirely with a binary editor. Also what version of Ghostscript are you using ? I can't find that message anywhere in current code. I'm pretty sure it would be a warning anyway, not an error.

Comment: @KenS the error is not shown on the Ghostscript but what my intentions are is to convert this file into PDF/A3 after the fonts are embedded, so when I try to convert to pdf/a3 it shows me this error, "CIDset in subset font is incomplete" in Adobe preflight. I tried using online converts to PDF/A3a like freepdfconvert.com and it actually perfectly makes it to a PDF/A3 without any font errors, not sure how they are embedding this font (AlbanyWTJ). I have their PDF with me and I can extract that font and embed it over here? This font is already embedded to the PDF and not sure if we can re-embed

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me. I thought that PDF/A required fonts to not be subset (at least A-1, not sure about 3) in which case using a subset font is invalid. Possibly PDF/A-3 requires a CIDSet, I can't remember off the top of my head I'd have to go read the spec. I wouldn't touch Adobe preflight anyway, use VeraPDF instead.

Comment: @KenS I use veraPDF also, both shows same error. Is there any possibility that we can fix this using Ghostscript, the website I previously mentioned is able to fix this error when we convert to PDF/A3. Not sure how they can re-embed the same font with a complete CIDset.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do so, however I can't really help without seeing the PDF file. You could open a bug report and attach the file there.

Comment: @KenS I have a suggestion, using gs is it possible to remove a CIDSet of a font?

Comment: Using Ghostscript, no, or at least not without altering the pdfwrite code. Ghostscript does not preserve the data from the input, it **generates** the data. As described in the documentation https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/VectorDevices.html